# Python signxml XML signature package. Set signature id

Tags: python, xml, xml-signature

I have an issue tryton to assign an Id to the ds:Signature tag. According to https://signxml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
The SAML assertion schema specifies a location for the enveloped XML signature (between <Issuer> and <Subject>). To sign a SAML assertion in a schema-compliant way, insert a signature placeholder tag at that location before calling XMLSigner: <ds:Signature Id="placeholder"></ds:Signature>.
```

Result from this reference is somethin like that

`<ds:Signature"><ds:SignedInfo>...`

But, what I need is something like

`<ds:Signature Id="signatureKG"><ds:SignedInfo>....`

My code is

```
        data = etree.parse('%s.xml' % filepath_source)
        signer = XMLSigner(
            method=methods.enveloped,
            signature_algorithm='rsa-sha1',
            digest_algorithm='sha1',
            c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'
        )

        if cert and len(cert) > 0:
            signed = signer.sign(
                data, key=key, cert=cert)
            xml_doc = etree.ElementTree(signed)
            signed_data = etree.tostring(signed)
            verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(
                signed_data, x509_cert=cert).signed_xml
        else:
            xml_doc = data

        xml_doc.write(
            '%s.xml' % filepath_target,
            pretty_print=True,
            xml_declaration=True,
            encoding='utf-8',
            standalone='no'
        )
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

```
from lxml import etree as e, objectify

objectify.deannotate(root_element, cleanup_namespaces=True)

e.SubElement(root_element,'{http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#}Signature',Id='placeholder',nsmap={None:'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'})
```

Comment: Can you provide a brief explanation of your answer?